# Why not use `@GenIgnore(GenIgnore.PERMITTED_TYPE)` for every method?

Tags: vert.x

I see that in vertx-cassandra-client, some methods are annotated with `@GenIgnore(GenIgnore.PERMITTED_TYPE)` (allowing their corresponding RxJava methods to be generated) and some with `@GenIgnore` (and has not rxified APIs)

How does one decide which is PERMITTED_TYPE and which isn't

e.g., [execute with collector](https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-cassandra-client/blob/5bf2ef3e649481e31c1f153cc705bc9f3040c7c8/src/main/java/io/vertx/cassandra/CassandraClient.java#L154)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Execute with `Collector` is not very useful for the Rxified API: RxJava has operators to collect items which work well with backpressure.